# How to add leaflet custom map locations

Tags: leaflet, overlays

I'm trying to add plain text as an overlay to my leaflet map with custom tiles. I don't want them bound to a marker on popup or as a mouse hover. Is there a way to add text to the locations of a map that would change size dynamically based on the zoom level?

please advise as the I'm not seeing anything in the Leaflet API...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the L.DivIcon for this. API [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon). This lets you represent an icon with ANY HTML that you define.

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon', html: '<b>Hello!</b>});
L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Obviously, where the HTML is inserted, you can use any HTML you want.

Will this work for you? You mention you don't want to use a marker, but is there a specific reason why a DivIcon wouldn't work?

Comment: I have tried it to implement exactly what the API has for it's example and I get the following chrome error when Inspecting the Element:  uncaught typeError: Cannot call method 'createIcon' of undefined

Comment: What I want is to treat text like a route/poly-line to associate it with grid locations so that I can see a label for a particular region that is in view on my custom tile

Comment: If you want to treat text like a route/line, then yeah, DivIcon will only get you a point, and you won't be able to snap it to a line. This plugin however might help: https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath It lets you write text along a polyline, and the text will wrap around the line.